# getByTitle() is not returning Sharepoint List

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, list, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to fetch couple of SharePoint(2013) lists from Jquery using ajax call, like below

```
$.ajax({
url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top="+maxReturnedRows,
method: "GET",
async: false,
headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
success: function (data) {

        listArray = data.d.results;         

    },
error: function (data) {
    alert('Error in AJAX-Call to '+listname);
    failure(data);
}
```

});

Where url contain URL of SharePoint site. 
This call is giving me below error,

**Error Code: -1, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
Error Message: The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

JSON Response:-

```
"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"de-DE\",\"value\":\"The given key was not present in the dictionary.\"}}}"
```

I have tried to debug the issue in Browser using below URL

```
 <baseurl>+ "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')
```

I received XML response with List Metada, but if I try to get Items of that list using below URL,

```
<baseurl> + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/Items
```

I get 500 error, I suspect because of same issue.

as another option,  tried to fetch same list using 'guid' like below,

```
    <baseurl>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

and it is working if I tried to access Items of this list, I get error 500

```
<baseurl>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')/Iems
```

Please let me know, how to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A list has two "names". When first created through the UI, the entered name is used as the root URL and also as the title. You can then change the title of the list, but the URL stays the same.

Here's what a renamed list's properties look like from PowerShell for a list created as "Cars2" and then later renamed:

```
PS C:\> $calcdemo.lists["Cars for sale"] | select title,rootfolder

Title         RootFolder
-----         ----------
Cars For Sale Lists/Cars2
```

As the REST "getByTitle" uses the title property and not the URL, in your sample code the "listname" variable would need to be "Cars for sale", not "Cars2".

Also, if the list title includes Unicode characters, you may need to escape those characters.

Comment: Thank you Mike for your response, My apologies but I think my question was not clear and specific. I have updated the question text with more specific error.

Comment: What kind of list is it?

Comment: The API URL you listed works fine in my lists and items. Have you tested it with other lists in the same site? What's the Title / name of the list? Is the "listname" variable a simple string? No newline or other special characters. I have a SharePoint REST tester that might be of help: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html

Comment: I have tested with other list and it is working for them. These are only two list for those it is not working. These are User Defined List created by Templates. These list name (title) contains underscore (_), but I have created new list with same templates and tried to give simpler name (only text no space, no special character), but still it is not working. I have noticed that untill list empty, rest service does not fail and return and empty XML but once i put data in list it start giving this error.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem column. Try bringing back just one or two columns and see if that works.        $select=Title

Answer (score 0):

```
url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items?$top="+maxReturnedRows,
```

you should get list items by **guid**:

for example :

```
 /_api/web/lists('%7B326038AE-D47E-454D-AAD4-5440E6133EF2%7D')
```